# Unable to find course mode in edx as superuser

Tags: python, django, edx

I have install edx in vagrant. I am trying to create a paid course using default cybersource.(For testing & I need to use Paypal)

For that i have follow [this link](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Paid-Certificates/). Here I have changed in lms common.py(all as true).

```
ENABLE_PAID_COURSE_REGISTRATION = True
ENABLE_SHOPPING_CART            = True
CC_PROCESSOR = The Default one
MULTIPLE_ENROLLMENT_ROLES = True
PAID_COURSE_REGISTRATION_CURRENCY = ['usd', '$']
STORE_BILLING_INFO  = True
CC_MERCHANT_NAME = XXXX
PAYMENT_SUPPORT_EMAIL = a valid one
```

Now when I am opening studio admin dashboard , I am not able to find 'Course Modes'.
I have already created two course as free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't access this through your Studio dashboard. You should be going to your django administration via:

```
yourdomain/admin
```

and more specifically:

```
yourdomain/admin/course_modes/coursemode/
```

Hope this helps!